# How can we open the Maps app for ios 6 within the app interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-maps

I am using the following code  for Map turn by turn navigation for iOS 6,

```
Class mapItemClass = [MKMapItem class];
    if (mapItemClass && [mapItemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)])
    {
        // Create an MKMapItem to pass to the Maps app
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate =
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(16.775, -3.009);
        MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate
                                                       addressDictionary:nil];
        MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
        [mapItem setName:@"My Place"];
        // Pass the map item to the Maps app
        [mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];


    }
```

It's redirecting me onto the Maps app so ,What i need,i need to open up this within my app interface so as user can remain in the app and not quit the app interface.

Please suggest some ideas to control this.

Comment: you can add MKMapView and create custom navbar to navigate

Answer (score 1):

[`MKMapKit`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) does not support navigation in [`MKMapView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205), you will need to send the user to map.app.

Your only option is to build the navigation your self if you really want to turn by turn navigation with in your app.

Comment: Does we use the Navit Api for the same as it's doing almost same work or does Navit has provided any api for ios?

Comment: Sorry my not familiar with the any Navit api? Also that is a new question, you should ask a new question if you want an answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

As rckoenes said, you have to implement this yourself if you don't want to launch an external app.

If you plan to do a simple version of turn-by-turn navigation, you can get the relevant data via the Google Maps Directions API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

From the JSON (or xml) response you get the driving instructions and location data for every step and waypoint. Also a string under the tag "overview_polyline" is provided here. You can draw the route directly on the map by using this string as GMSPath if your're working with the Google Maps IOS SDK.
The main challenge of a self-written navigation app is constructing a robust logic for tracking the user and providing turn-by-turn instructions accurately, as well as exception handling (e.g. losing signal in tunnels...). But just showing the route and the instructions visually should be relatively easy.